# how can I start a program without it stealing the focus of my mouse, display, and keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Opera is the biggest pain, I start it and go on to work on something else and seconds later opera appears and I have to switch back to what I was doing.
I start a number of programs, including Opera , with a script, but I want them to respect my 'do not disturb' preference.
there are more complicated ways to get xdotool to hack at it after the fact, but I want to start a program truly in the background from the getgo.
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Focal, kernel 5.4.0-53-generic, Ubuntu Gnome Version: 3.36.1-5ubuntu1

Comment: No idea what window manager/desktop environment you are using. The answer, however, will depend on that.

Comment: hi, sorry. for that omission. Ubuntu

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Focal
kernel 5.4.0-53-generic
Ubuntu Gnome

Comment: Edit your question and add relevant information directly in your question. Comments can disappear.

Comment: gnome version derived from 'apt-cache show gnome-shell | grep Version'